# R quantmod:getFinancials

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I'm trying to import the financials statements of all the companies listed on the NYSE whose market cap is in greater than the first quartile of the sample.
Here is my code :

```
require(TTR)
require(quantmod)
data.init="2013/01/01"
start.date <- as.numeric(gsub("/", "",data.init))
nyse.symbols <- stockSymbols("NYSE")[,-c(3,5)]
nyse.symbols <- na.omit(nyse.symbols[which(nyse.symbols[,"MarketCap"]>0),])

######## Selection Criteria
# Filter 1 : stock mkt cap > 1st quartile --> remove the less liquid stocks
mktcap.filter <- quantile(nyse.symbols[,"MarketCap"],0.25)
nyse.symbols <- nyse.symbols[which(nyse.symbols[,"MarketCap"]>mktcap.filter),]

# Filter 2 : 
nyse.fs <-  new.env()
tickers.fs <- nyse.symbols[,1]
tickers.fs <- tickers.fs[- match(c("IHG","AF","BAP","BBD","BBDO"),tickers.fs)]
lapply(tickers.fs, getFinancials,env=nyse.fs)
```

I've removed the following stocks `c("IHG","AF","BAP","BBD","BBDO")`because `quantmod`does not manage to import the financials statements: I've got an error message like that :

```
Error in thead[x]:thead[x + 1] : NA/NaN argument
In addition: There were 39 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

and here is what I get when using the `warnings()` function:

Warning messages (I've got 39 errors messages of this type):

```
1: In readLines(tmp) :
  incomplete final line found on '/var/folders/9q/pwdpb5nj7bb8jjc_kb3np__h0000gn/T//RtmpeUS9Uh/file7de4698fa5b'
2: In readLines(tmp) :
  incomplete final line found on '/var/folders/9q/pwdpb5nj7bb8jjc_kb3np__h0000gn/T//RtmpeUS9Uh/file7de655c9092'
3: In readLines(tmp) :
  incomplete final line found on '/var/folders/9q/pwdpb5nj7bb8jjc_kb3np__h0000gn/T//RtmpeUS9Uh/file7de2017953b'
```

I've found the problematic stocks step by step. What I would like to do is automatically  get rid of all the stocks whose financials statements are not available.
Any idea?

Comment: Can you please describe the error message? What do you get when you run `getFinancials("IHG");viewFin(IHG.f)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the call to `getFinancials` between `tryCatch`. Here an example:

```
options(warn=-1)  ## optional to not get horrible quantlib messages!
 ## here I choose 2 goods symbols and 2 bad symbols    
 ll <- lapply(c("AF","IHG","BAP",ny.se[1,1]), function(x)
   tryCatch(getFinancials(x,env=nyse.fs),
                     error=function(e){print(paste(x,'not found'));NA}))
### "AF not found"
### "BAP not found"
options(warn=0)
## I apply to remove NA 
rapply(ll,na.omit)
"IHG.f" "A.f"
```

Comment: What is the meaning of your error function? Should I enter in the error function the error message I get on the R console?

Comment: @marino89 it logs the error. you can replace the message "not foud" by any string, but returns NA. I use it in the rapply to filter the final list.

Comment: Small correction: perhaps `ny.se[1,1]` should be `nyse.symbols[1,1]`? Help for those who are copying and pasting.