# Error in R quantmod --getFinancials [ Object not found]

Tags: r, quantmod

I am using `getFinancials` of `R quantmod`. I am not getting quote for a company which data is already there on Google finance. I am trying to get financials of following company:

`getFinancials(Symbol = ACHI, src = 'google')`

What may be the issue? Is it due that it's not being traded in popular markets?

**Error**

> Error in strsplit(Symbol, ";") : object 'ACHI' not found

Comment: do not forget the quotation marks for the 'symbol'; 
Symbol=one or more valid google symbol, as a "character" vector or semi-colon delimited string

Comment: It seems that this issue is not traded on major markets but only OTC. I assume that such data is generally not available in `quantmod`.

Comment: @WD11 After putting quote I am getting different error:
`Error in thead[x]:thead[x + 1] : NA/NaN argument`

Comment: Have a look at this post [quantmod:getFinancials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043728/r-quantmodgetfinancials) 
Seems someone had the same/similar problem back in 2013.

Comment: Having another quick look and some sample testing I guess that quantmod or google finance, however you wanna put it, has trouble with providing/fetching OTCMKTS (OTC markets) financials. Basically getFinancials calls itself '... utility to download financial statements for publically traded companies' and I guess OTC contradicts that definition, so "works as designed". Only solution would be starting to scrape the data off the website yourself, I guess.